# PostgreSQL adding specific value to missing cells after lag function

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, lag, coalesce

If I run the query:

```
SELECT status,
       created_at,
       lead(created_at) over(partition BY id
                             ORDER BY updated_at) ended_at
FROM salesdb.orders
```

I get the following result:

```
| status    | created_at          | ended_at            |
| Opened    | 2019-11-12 11:46:11 | 2019-11-15 12:04:13 |
| Pending   | 2019-11-15 12:04:13 | 2019-11-19 23:03:24 |
| Completed | 2019-11-19 23:03:24 |                     |
| Opened    | 2019-11-14 11:46:11 | 2019-11-17 12:04:13 |
| Pending   | 2019-11-17 12:04:13 | 2019-11-20 23:03:24 |
| Completed | 2019-11-20 23:03:24 |                     |
```

I would like to insert a specific end date into the missing cells as `'2019-12-31'`

Like so:

```
| status    | created_at          | ended_at            |
| Opened    | 2019-11-12 11:46:11 | 2019-11-15 12:04:13 |
| Pending   | 2019-11-15 12:04:13 | 2019-11-19 23:03:24 |
| Completed | 2019-11-19 23:03:24 | 2019-12-31 00:00:00 |
| Opened    | 2019-11-14 11:46:11 | 2019-11-17 12:04:13 |
| Pending   | 2019-11-17 12:04:13 | 2019-11-20 23:03:24 |
| Completed | 2019-11-20 23:03:24 | 2019-12-31 00:00:00 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `coalesce`:

```
select status,
       created_at,
       coalesce(
           lead(created_at) over(partition by id order by updated_at), 
           '2019-12-31') ended_at
from salesdb.orders
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the three argument form of `lead()`:

```
SELECT status,
       created_at,
       lead(created_at, 1, '2019-12-31') over (partition BY id
                                               order by updated_at
                                              ) as ended_at
FROM salesdb.orders
```